# DevTools console text is cut when zoomed in

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

*Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

I use Google Chrome DevTools to make some screencasts about JavaScript and I'm used to zoom in a lot to make mobile friendly screencasts.

Today I zoom in and my text is now cut off at the bottom when I type in the console.

Does anyone have the same problem? Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I zoomed in like 5 or 6 times. My default font size is not 16px but 18px, I changed it back to 16px but it didn't change a thing, the text is still cut off.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome. Consider reporting it on https://crbug.com. As for fixing, try installing a *custom devtools theme*.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the tip, I'll try that. I already filed a bug from Chrome > Help > Report an Issue... menu. Do you think I should file another one on crbug.com?

Comment: Using a custom theme did the trick! Thanks @wOxxOm.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by pressing Command + / - several times